# DRF - Create Serializer: accepting ForeignKey data with Non-Primary Field value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am totally new to Django/DRF, and trying to work with Create/Read/Update of a Model.

Here are the dummy model/serializers:

`AddressModel` and `UserModel`:

```py
class AddressModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  street = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UserModel(models.Model):
  email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

And I have `BaseSerializer` and `WriteSerializer`:

```
class UserBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  email = serializers.CharField(required=True)
  address = AddressSerializer()

  class Meta:
     model = User
     fields = ['email', 'address']


class UserWriteSerializer(UserBaseSerializer):

   class Meta(UserBaseSerializer.Meta):
      read_only_fields = ["created_by"]

   def create(self, validated_data):
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Now the problem is, reading data through BaseSerializer, is working fine, I am able to display `User` and `Address` on UI correctly. But having issues with Create/Update.
For creating new user from UI, I have a select dropdown for Address, which has some constant values, these constant values are on UI side, it's not getting fetched from Backend, but backend will have related row in database.

And the issue is, I am not sending primary key of the address, I am sending `name` field of the address in the post call, so how can I still handle `name` field on Create serializer to store correct address, and return it in success?

`validated_data` in `create` method is not having `Address` instance. It's omitting that, may be due to non-primary field value.

**Solution 1#:**
One solution can be to fetch address from backend to display in select dropdown, so that I can send address id in api call.

**Solution 2#:**
Another solution could be to use `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and convert data using `to_internal_values` and `to_representation_value`:

```
class UserWriteSerializer(UserBaseSerializer):
    address = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Address.objects.all(), required=True
    )

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        address = Address.objects.filter(name=data.get("name")).first()
        data["address"] = address.id

        return super().to_internal_value(data)

   def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data["address"] = AddressSerializer(instance.address).data
        return data
```

Above solution works, but `mypy` throws error that I am changing data type of `address` in `WriteSerializer`, while `BaseSerializer` has different type.

Is there another way to handle this non-primary field value in WriteSerializer or somewhere else?

Comment: Can you share the request data you used? Curious because `validated_data` should still have the `address` in `create` if you passed the correct format, and would fail in `is_valid` if you didn't

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is supported when using the [`SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield).  Just specify your name field as the "slug" and ensure it is unique.

```
class UserWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field="name",
        queryset=Address.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "address", "email", "..."]
```

It is a good idea to split serializers, as you have done, for `create/update` vs. `list`.  Be careful with inheriting, though, since any fields you add in the `list` view will automatically be editable in the `create`.  Its safer to just make them entirely separate.